# Magento Installation set up is not completing

Tags: magento-enterprise

Currently we are using magento enterprise 1.14.1.0. we downloaded all the files from server. When I am trying to configure it with my local machine, I could not complete the process.

I can directly configure with DB by updating the DB details. Even though, I would like to install from beginning. So that I can assume, My machine is having adequate features like curl, soap extension in terms of Prerequisites.

I could able to reach out till last step. But in the last step, I filled all the form values and I hit enter button. It is taking me to first step of installation. I cleared all the cache. The local.xml file had created but it was blank.

What was the problem? Am I missing something while installing? Should I do anything else here?

Comment: I just upgraded to new version. And also files got changed.  Now it looks good. I completed the installation steps.

Comment: You should add your own answer and mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded to new version. And also files got changed. Now it looks good. I completed the installation steps